# Windows 8 Need to create a wizard custom control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, custom-controls, winrt-xaml

### Heading ##I am creating a windows 8 application in which i need to create a wizard control. This control will look like as shown below:

[image]

The Steps should enable navigation to only previous or current steps the next steps should be disabled and should only be enabled once navigated from next button. Like shown in the diagram step 4 and step 5 are disabled as current step is step 3.

On each step there will be a form that I think should be a custom control.

I need to make this wizard dynamic such that just send list of custom control it should automatically generate all the UI like shown in the diagram.

How should i create or approach this as there can be n numbers of form I need to even optimize this for performance. Please let me know your suggestions?

Created a sample code after suggestion:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="lstVwSelectItem" >
            <ListViewItem>1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>2</ListViewItem>
        </ListView>

        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=lstVwSelectItem}" 
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myAppBarSelector}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello 1" Foreground="White" />
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello 2" Foreground="White" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>   
    </Grid>

 public class AppBarSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (item == null) return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);

            var contentControl = (ContentControl)container;
            var templateKey = Convert.ToString(item);

            if (contentControl.Resources.ContainsKey(templateKey))
            {
                return (DataTemplate)contentControl.Resources[templateKey];
            }
            else
            {
                return (DataTemplate)contentControl.Resources["0"];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't really seem like you might have performance issues in what you are trying to achieve other than possible memory leaks if you do something incorrectly. Also I think your question is a bit too broad. What have you tried, what are your specific problems? Are you trying to create a reusable control that you or other people would want to use in multiple applications or just something quick for your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part on the left looks like an `ItemsControl` bound to a list of steps. The part on the right side looks like a panel with two buttons bound to `ICommand` properties and a `ContentControl` bound to the `CurrentStep` view model and a `ContentTemplateSelector` set to a `DataTemplateSelector` implementation. It's likely that instead of `ContentControl` and `DataTemplate` with a custom control for each step you could just have another `ItemsControl` bound to a list of form field view models with an `ItemTemplate` or `ItemTemplateSelector` to enable editing each of those.

Comment: Sure having content control and bind that to the selected index of the listview on the left hand side and then picking up the correct DataTemplate based on the selected step would help to accomplish the task. I have created some sample and edited in the question above. Can you let me know if its correct or it can be improved better. and I need to even disable the next steps how can i accomplish that?

Comment: Hi Filip can you please send me your comments...

Comment: Hi Jerry, I have created this but i want to dynamically add custom control for each step in an MVVM framework. I want that user should not be able to go to next step before completing previous step. How can i achieve this using flipview in MVVM fashion.

Comment: You could bind the `FlipView` to an `ItemsSource` collection that only includes the set of steps that the user is allowed to navigate to and add new steps as the previous steps are completed. Also - are you sure you really need to prevent skipping through the steps? Perhaps you could just highlight the incomplete steps in the index that you show on the left. It's often a sort artificial limitation people impose on the wizards that doesn't really serve a purpose and only infuriates the user...